# Best way to arrange elements in div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I want to build a simple event box, to replace the default one in a calendar (react-big-calendar for reference, but I don't think it matters)

I would like to make it as responsive as possible, but I have started with a very static box, which corresponds to what I would like to see on a big screen.
[Simple fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c71bz0dg/)

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.event-slot-component {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #64a7DD;
  border: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 2px;
}

.event-slot-start-time {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.event-slot-end-time {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.event-slot-label {
  font-size: 1em;
  top: 8px;
  right: 5px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="event-slot-component">
    <div class="event-slot-start-time">17h</div>
    <div class="event-slot-end-time">21h</div>
    <div class="event-slot-label">Occupied Slot</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My goal is to have a 'centered, eventually slightly to the right' label,
and two small indications on the left that correspond to the start and end of the event.
I have tried using flexbox, coming from other StackOverflow answers, and it does seem to be able to do that somehow, but I have not managed to display the three elements properly. Any insight on a clean solution to achieve this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest with the existing markup is to use Flexbox with `column` direction on the 2 date values and then position the label absolute using `transform`

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.event-slot-component {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #64a7DD;
  border: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding:2px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.event-slot-start-time,
.event-slot-end-time {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  flex-grow: 1;                      /*  share the vertical space equal  */
}
.event-slot-label {
  position:absolute;
  font-size: 1em;
  top: 50%;
  left: calc(50% + 10px);            /*  adjust px value for horiz. offset  */
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);   /*  vert./hor. center the label  */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="event-slot-component">
    <div class="event-slot-start-time">17h</div>
    <div class="event-slot-end-time">21h</div>
    <div class="event-slot-label">Occupied Slot</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If you want a good responsive solution, use Flexbox all the way, here with a wrapper for the date's

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.event-slot-component {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #64a7DD;
  border: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding:2px;
  display: flex;
}
.event-slot-time {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.event-slot-start-time,
.event-slot-end-time {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  flex-grow: 1;                  /*  share the vertical space equal  */
}
.event-slot-label {
  flex-grow: 1;                  /*  fill the remaining horizontal space  */
  font-size: 1em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;           /*  vertical center the label text  */
  justify-content: center;       /*  horizontal center the label text  */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="event-slot-component">
    <div class="event-slot-time">
      <div class="event-slot-start-time">17h</div>
      <div class="event-slot-end-time">21h</div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-slot-label">Occupied Slot</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Accepting this answer because closer to my original question, but thanks to @scramio as well for the earlier explanation with flexbox!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to nest your flexboxes. That's what's so wonderful about it!

To explain, what I did was created three wrappers.

One to hold the entire event.

One to hold your event times.

One to hold the status.

We used flex box to butt the event times and status-wrapper against each other. The event times only take up as much space as the text utilizes (plus a little padding). The status wrapper takes up 100% of its usable space.

Then status wrapper is set to flex box using the justify-content and align-items properties. This centers the status.

The status text container is used in the same way to center the status text itself.

```css
.event-wrapper {
background-color: #eee;
display: flex;
}

.event-times-wrapper {
background-color: skyblue;
padding-left: 0.5rem;
padding-right: 0.5rem;
}

.status-wrapper {
width:100%;
display: flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content: center;
}

.status-text {
height: 100%;
display:flex;
align-items: center;
padding-left: 1rem;
padding-right: 1rem;
background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<article class="event-wrapper">
  <div class="event-times-wrapper">
    <p class="event-start">9:00a</p>
    <p class="event-end">10:00a</p>
  </div>
  <div class="status-wrapper">
    <div class="status-text">Busy</div>
  </div>
</article>
```

As OP requested later, a sample without special containers.

```css
.container {
background-color: #eee;
position: relative;
width: 100vw;
height:6rem;
}

.event-slot-component div {
font-family: sans-serif;
color: white;
background-color: skyblue;
height:3rem;
float:left;
padding-left: 1rem;
padding-right: 1rem;
width:10%;
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
}

.event-slot-component div:nth-child(2) {
background-color:red;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left: 0;
}

.event-slot-component div:last-of-type {
margin-left:25%;
background-color: tomato;
float:left;
height: 6rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="event-slot-component">
    <div class="event-slot-start-time">17h</div>
    <div class="event-slot-end-time">21h</div>
    <div class="event-slot-label">Occupied Slot</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly. is there a way to do this without adding container divs? I like the idea of flexbox but if there must be intermediate divs, I'm pretty sure the same is acheivable without flex :)

Comment: Yes, as soon as my edit to my answer is reviewed it will be posted. It still uses flexbox, but does not require you to add any additional containers. You can remove the flexbox portions and it will still work, but the text will not be centered as nicely. You can use percentages to achieve similar effects, but flexbox solves problems for responsive web design. Percentages can get real wonky depending on window size.

Comment: LGSon, thank you for denying that edit request -- that was an accident, as was copying your code. Thanks for following up. Hope all is well now.